# Can't seem to get my head around the 'list difference' (\\) operator

Tags: list, haskell, element, set-difference

I have heard the term 'list difference' `(\\)` operator in Haskell but still don't quite know how to get my head around it. Any examples or ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply put, it takes two lists, goes through the second and for each item, removes the first instance of the same item from the first list.

```
> [1..10] \\ [2, 3, 5, 8]
[1,4,6,7,9,10]
> [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2] \\ [2]
[1,1,2,1,2]
> [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2] \\ [2, 2]
[1,1,1,2]
> [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2] \\ [2, 2, 1]
[1,1,2]
```

Answer (score 9):

The [`(\\)` operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-Set.html#g:2) (and [the `difference` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-Set.html#v:difference)) implements [set difference](http://math.comsci.us/sets/difference.html), so, if you have two lists, `a` and `b`, it returns only those elements of `a` that are not in `b`, as illustrated:

[image]

Comment: But it actually implements multi-set difference; the argument lists are allowed to contain the same element multiple times.

Comment: if I have this declaration : diff :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]  and I want to find the difference between 2 lists? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

`xs \\ ys` is all the elements in `xs` that are not in `ys`. Maybe a list comprehension will clarify this:

```
xs \\ ys = [ x | x <- xs, x `notElem` ys ]
```

or, if you could do this in Haskell,

```
xs \\ ys = [ x | x `elem` xs, x `notElem` ys ]
```

This comes from [set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory)'s [set difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_difference#Relative_complement). The basic idea is that you are "subtracting" one collection of elements from another, hence the term "difference".

Comment: if I have this declaration : diff :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]  and I want to find the difference between 2 lists? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you have a list of things, for example cities. Let's take for instance this list:

```
a = ["London","Brussels","Tokio","Los Angeles","Berlin","Beijing"]
```

Now you want to remove all cities that are in Europe. You know, that those cities are in Europe:

```
b = ["Glasgow","Paris","Bern","London","Madrid","Amsterdam","Berlin","Brussels"]
```

To get a list of cities in `a`, that are not in Europe, so that are not in `b`, you can use `(\\)`:

```
a \\ b = ["Tokio","Los Angeles","Beijing"]
```

Comment: how would do this without the difference operator ?

Comment: @matthias You can implement `(\\)` as `a \\ b = filter (not . flip elem b) a`.

Comment: sorry 1 more thing... could you write that in non point free please?

Comment: @matthias That is about as point-free as it can get. I can add one more lambda if you like: `a \\ b = filter (\x -> not (x \`elem\` b)) a`.

Comment: oh thanks.. I actually did not want point free. I don't know that its called (new to this). I find point free harder to understand.  I think the way you wrote it now is easier to understand.

Comment: @matthias Sorry, I meant “that's about as non point-free as it can get” but I mixed up. I'm happy that I was able to help you.

Comment: if I have this declaration : diff :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]  and I want to find the difference between 2 lists? How should I proceed?

Comment: @Madalina Difference as in “symmetric difference”?

Comment: @fux: I have 2 lists, a and b, it returns only those elements of a that are not in b

Comment: @Madalina Then just use `diff = (\\)` whith `(\\)` from `Data.List`.